# LDAP search filter not working

Tags: java, spring-security, active-directory, spring-boot, ldap

In my spring boot / spring security java application the shown code works fine...

But now I want to restrict the users only from a specific sub directory in LDAP.
(mydomain.local/IT/USERS)

How can I restrict ?

I tried using provider.setSearchFilter(xxxx) and got the exception

```
o.s.s.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate    : Ignoring PartialResultException
```

**Java code:-**

```
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {

        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("mydomain.local", "ldap://server.mydomain.local:389");
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
    //  provider.setSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})");
        return provider;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting a filter but you aren't setting the value of the `{0}` argument anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Does it work with: `"&(sAMAccountName={0})"` instead of `"(sAMAccountName={0})"` ?

Comment: No it won't, as that's not legal syntax, and it would be pointless even if it was legal, and a question is not an answer.

Comment: Impoliteness consists largely in making personal remarks, and it isn't me who made them. Mind your manners here.